# What are the divisors of $q^{q+1} - 1$ for prime $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, other than $q - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

**Main Question**

> What are the divisors of $q^{q+1} - 1$ for $q$ a prime congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, other than $q - 1$?

**My Attempt**

Since $q$ is odd, $q+1$ is even so that $q^{q+1} - 1$ is a *difference of two squares*.  Therefore, we obtain
$$q^{q+1} - 1 = \bigg(q^{(q+1)/2} + 1\bigg)\cdot\bigg(q^{(q+1)/2} - 1\bigg).$$
I conjecture that
$$(q+1) \mid (q^{q+1} - 1),$$
but I do not see how to prove it.

**Added March 04 2017 (Manila time)**

Following [ajotatxe](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/132456)'s lead, if $q + 2$ is prime, I have
$$q^{q + 1} - 1 \equiv (-2)^{\phi(q + 2)} - 1 \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \pmod {q + 2}$$
by Euler's formula involving the totient function $\phi$, since $\gcd(-2, q + 2) = 1$ (because $q$ is an odd prime and $q+2$ is prime).

Therefore,
$$(q + 2) \mid (q^{q+1} - 1)$$
if $q + 2$ is prime.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $q+1$ is even,
$$q^{q+1}-1\equiv (-1)^{q+1}-1= 1-1=0\pmod{q+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, that was quick!  Are you able to spot any more factors for $q^{q+1} - 1$?

Comment: $q+2$, if $q+2$ is prime.

Comment: Following your lead, I have
$$q^{q + 1} - 1 \equiv (-2)^{\phi(q + 2)} - 1 \equiv 1 - 1 \pmod {q + 2}$$
by Euler's formula involving the totient function $\phi$, since $\gcd(-2, q + 2) = 1$ (because $q$ is an odd prime and $q+2$ is prime).

Is this correct?